# Bash - bind key to a string (not a function)

Tags: bash

How do I get a key binding to result in inserting arbitrary text at the command line? In zsh I do this:

```
bindkey -s "^[m" 'myspecialscript '
```

In bash, is there an equivalent? None of the built-in functions will do what I want.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/186985/linux-server-terminal-keyboard-shortcuts-to-run-commands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bind '"\e[[E": "/home/yourscript.sh\n"'` binds to f5 replace the first part with your key pref

Comment: excellent, that works. I'm not sure why I didn't try that earlier.