# what's the usage of 'bind' in bash

Tags: bash

I found something in a `.bashrc` file like:

```
bind '"\C-j": menu-complete'
bind 'set completion-ignore-case on'
```

if I remove the 'bind',the result seems no different, so what's the usage of the 'bind' here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680936/bash-bind-key-to-a-string-not-a-function

Comment: [Read the manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash).  (Search for bind readline-command)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bind` is used for [`readline`](http://www.gnu.org/software/readline/) library.

If you remove the first one, <kbd>Ctrl-j</kbd> will not do auto completion for you.
If you remove the second one, auto completion for file name is case-sensitive.

---

You can use `help` command to view `builtin` command's manual.

```
$ type bind
bind is a shell builtin

$ help bind
bind: bind [-lpvsPVS] [-m keymap] [-f filename] [-q name] [-u name] [-r keyseq] [-x keyseq:shell-command] [keyseq:readline-function or readline-command]
    Set Readline key bindings and variables.
    ...SKIPPED...
```